# Jenkins dynamic pipeline parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, consul

I have a jenkins pipeline which gives the user a list of keys from Consul, the user should choose one option (using active choice parameter), I need the pipeline to dynamically generate the list of "sub keys" (depends on the user first choice, for example: key/path/${user_choice} ) and let the user to choose a sub key
my current code his:

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'consul kv get -keys --http-addr=X key/path/ | awk -F / \'{print $(NF-1)}\''].execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitFor()
return sout.tokenize()
```

It works fine till now, but "active choice reactive parameter" is not acting dynamically and refuse to relate to the user's first choice. I haven't found any other useful plugin

Any help?
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you can't have an interactive command prompt in Jenkins. However, you can use the `input` step to get feedback and use it throughout the pipeline like so:

```
def keys = sh(script: 'consul kv get -keys --http-addr=X key/path/ | awk -F / \'{print $(NF-1)}\'', returnStdout: true).trim().tokenize('\n')

def choice = input message: 'Please choose a sub-key', parameters: [choice(choices: keys, description: '', name: 'Subkeys')]

println "You chose $choice"
```